# Palindrome Check of List in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand the basics of lists in python. I've written a sample code for Palindrome string check in python. I'm trying to understand why it is not working. I'm comparing a string parameter with a list parameter.

Can anyone explain to me why the below code is giving a wrong output?

```
class Palindrome:

    @staticmethod
     def is_palindrome(word):
         i = 0
         l = len(word)
         rev = []
         print(l)
         while l > 0:
             rev.insert(i, word[l - 1])
             i = i + 1
             l = l - 1

         if rev == word:
             print(test)
             print(word)
             return True
         else:
             print(rev)
             print(word)
             return False

print(Palindrome.is_palindrome('tatat'))
```

**Output for the above code is**:

```
$python main.py
5
['t', 'a', 't', 'a', 't']
tatat
False
```

One more thing is the following: Why is it printing the array value like **['t', 'a', 't', 'a', 't']** instead of **tatat**
I have tried the `append()` method as well but no use and the result is the same.

Comment: There are no 'arrays' in python. You seem to be comparing a `list` and a `string` (`if rev == word:`). I think these will never compare equal.

Comment: `[]` is a list in python. Its printing `['t', 'a', 't', 'a', 't']` because you take each letter and put it in a list - `rev.insert(i,word[l-1])`

Comment: What's the output that you're looking for?

Comment: There isn't even an [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array) anywhere in your code.

Comment: Well you "initilize" `rev` as a list so printing it out prints a list.

Comment: It seems as if you're comparing Java to Python imho. You may want to read some documentation on Python lists and compare those to arrays in Java. It is also difficult for us to help you because we don't know the specific output that you are looking for in this scenario.

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo: btw the required output is obvious from the code the OP posted. The OP wants `True` to be printed as the last line of the output.

Comment: @quamrana  "The required output is obvious from the code the OP posted" is ambiguous. Be specific

Comment: Here I'm trying to understand the things. I don't know why people are down voting the question. We are all here to learn something and not to discourage each other. Coming to the question I've asked where I'm doing wrong and  I was expecting the OUTPUT to be "TRUE" since I don't know that I was **comparing string with List **. You people can simple say it like "you are comparing string with List". That's it. why you people are making the things complicated. I'm sorry if I hurted someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why people over react here. If anyone comes here for any help we should help him (if we can ) or at least don't discourage him. What's wrong in my question? If there is any wrong let me know in a smooth way instead of attacking altogether. We are here to learn something and grow together.
Anyhow, here is the solution for the Question that I posted above:

```
class Palindrome:

@staticmethod
def is_palindrome(word):
    i= 0
    l= len(word)
    rev = ""
    print(l)
    while(l>0):
        rev += word[l - 1]
        l = l-1
        i =i+1
    if (rev == word):
        print(rev)
        print(word)
        return True
    else:
        print(rev)
        print(word)
        return False
print(Palindrome.is_palindrome('tatat'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting characters into a list, the end result of which is still a list and explicitly not a string; that is why your palindrome test returns `False` because what you compare is `['t', 'a', 't', 'a', 't'] == 'tatat'`.

If you want to do this correctly you need to declare `rev` as an empty string and append to it.

```
 rev = ''
 for i in range(len(word)):
     rev += word[len(word) - i]
```

Comment: Hi @MarcelZoll, Thanks for the answer. It is working well with little bit modification to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a `string` (your word input) with a `list` of characters. You will have to [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) your characters into a `string` before comparing it to your original `string`.

Comment: Either changing the list to a string or the string to a list before comparing would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below answer will sum up almost all the queries about the differences between List and Array:

- The main difference between these two data types is the operations
  you can perform on them. For example, you can divide an array by 3
  and it will divide each element of array by 3. Same can not be done
  with the list.
- The list is the part of python's syntax so it doesn't need to be
  declared whereas you have to declare the array before using it.
- You can store values of different data-types in a list
  (heterogeneous), whereas in Array you can only store values of only
  the same data-type (homogeneous).
- Arrays being rich in functionalities and fast, it is widely used for
  arithmetic operations and for storing a large amount of data -
  compared to the list.
- Arrays take less memory compared to lists.